# Understanding the divergence theorem and how it leads to Gauss' law

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, divergence-operator

I don't see why Gauss' Law holds for volumes that contain no source or sink. I am trying to understand Gauss' Law as a general effect of any vector field, so I would like any electrostatics left out of the discussion.

For an arbitrary 3-dimensional region $R$ placed in a vector field **F**, the divergence theorem states that the flux integrated across the *surface* of the volume $R$ is equal to the divergence of the vector field **F** integrated over the entire *volume* of $R$:

$\begin{equation}
\oint_S \textbf{F}\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}}\>dS = \int_V \nabla\cdot\textbf{F}\>dV
\end{equation}$

This much makes sense to me, intuitively and mathematically. But, Gauss' Law then states that if the region $R$ does *not contain a source or sink*, then  the left-hand side of the equation above is zero (and hence the right hand side is zero as well).

But this doesn't make sense to me. For example, consider a rectangular region $\bar{R}$ in a two dimensional vector field **k** such that

$\textbf{k} = x\hat{x}$

All boundaries of $\bar{R}$ are parallel to either the $x$ or $y$ axis. I will refer to the "left" and "right" sides of the region $\bar{R}$ as those parallel to the $y$ axis, and the "top" and "bottom" sides as those parallel to the $x$ axis.

The magnitude of **k** is increasing in the $+x$ direction, so any rectangle $\bar{R}$ drawn in the $+x$ region will have a larger positive flux on its right side, as compared to a smaller negative flux on its left side, and zero flux on the top and bottom.

This region contains no sources or sinks (nor does any region at all in this field), but I don't see how the divergence integrated across the area of $\bar{R}$ could be zero, or how the value of **k** integrated across the boundary of the shape could be zero either. It seems that in either case it should be positive.

Comment: I don't know what your definition of source is, but as the divergence of your vector field is $1$, I would say every point of the plane is a source.

Comment: Hmmm... I am confused in juggling between pure math and physical intuition, then. The vector field that I have described, **k**, is exactly what a gravitational or electric field might look like in a small region that does not contain the field-generating charge or mass. But, Gauss law says that a region $R$ which does not contain said charge or mass (field source) has zero flux through it.

Comment: Are you sure?  What charge geometry would produce such a vector field?  It seems to make the electric field horizontal, the charged region would need to be akin to a vertical line.  In that case, Coloumb's law would give a constant electric field, which has zero divergence.  But my last physics course was over 25 years ago, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Think of a coffee cup. If you pour coffee into the cup then across any closed surface connected to the rim of your cup the net flow of coffee will be negative ("into" the cup). If there is no hole in or pump into the cup then gausses law means the total added amount of coffee increases by the same amount as what passes the surface around the cup (in the inwards direction).

Comment: In a coffee maker however we could model it as a coffee-source, at some point in the machine the flow of water vanishes and is replaced by a flow of coffee. You input water and get coffee out, but no coffee enters and no water escapes. So there must be "something" that destroys the flow of water ( sink ) and that creates a flow of coffee ( source ). That would be the coffee beans (or powder). They are all tiny couplings of (water sink , coffee source) 's.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Just simply imagine a point mass creating a gravitational field. If you focus on a very small region, then all the field lines will appear parallel rather than radial (such as they do on the Earth right now, from our perspective). 

Gauss' Law would imply that any volume hovering above the Earth's surface has zero gravitational flux, but I don't see how that could be when the filed is obviously stronger on one side of the object (as with my example field **k**)

Comment: @mathreadler Ok... I'm not sure that any of this answers my question though. I guess I should start by simply clarifying; what is the most general possible expression of Guass' law?

Comment: @jphollowed: That is why I did not make an answer out of it. However it does not seem to me that the most general form of Gauss' law really is what you need but rather an intuitive way to explain the concepts.